# Gender and Age group identification from audio data set in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, librosa

I am a newbee in ML and trying to identify gender and age group of a speaker based on the audio files data set. I am trying to use *librosa* for this.

Can run up to this code and now don't know how to proceed further. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
for file in range(0,len(audio_files),1):
    audio, sfreq = lr.load(audio_files[file])
    time = np.arange(0,len(audio)) / sfreq

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(time,audio)
    ax.set(xlabel='time(s)', ylabel='Sound Amplitude')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure librosa is the best tool for this job. You may use it for feature extraction, but the real classification is probably better done using a CNN on the spectrograms.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.  will try using CNN